# Power fluctuates enough to make bedroom fan almost turn off

Tags: electrical

It's been happening a while. Lights flicker throughout house and my bedroom fan slows down a lot, kind of like when my ex used to bear down on her hair straightener. I mainly notice it when I go to bed, often times kind of late. Any thoughts? The fan is plugged into a power strip. It has fallen a few times. Haven't bought a new one yet to see of it's causing all of this.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like a house-wide or even neighborhood-wide problem, but we'll need more info to know. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I agree it could multiple problems. Start by cutting the problem down, tackle the power strip possibility first.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?

Answer (score 1):

That's a power supply problem, and a serious one.  If it is happening all over the house, and if any appliances will cause it, then it's a "lost neutral" -most likely on the power company's side of the meter.   That is their problem and they should fix it for free.   Call them and report an outage, since it is as serious as an outage.  Don't delay, either - this should be fixed right away before it does serious damage,